# Chrome bug while using html5 video and fullpage.js. Any solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, fullpage.js

On my project I'm using `fullpage.js` in the home page.

Then I want to add a video as background, however the video is ignoring the `autoplay` option and it doesn't start. but it does when you scroll down once and then up again.

It is working fine on firefox (and even on IE!).

You can see this behaviour on this **[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yzBNvq)**

chrome version: 60.0.3112.113 (Build oficial) (64 bits)

Anything I could add to my code to make it works, at least temporally?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you took a look at these questions: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/152
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/257

Comment: Ty for the links. No I didn't search there. Hope there's a solution.

Comment: (try `playsinline` attribute), autoplay` feature will also be dismissed in next browsers releases due to unneeded band usage...

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez Run `play()` on `afterLoad`, see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this statement at the end of the `afterLoad` callback. The video tag may be ready to autoplay, but the plugin is probably still rendering the sections to suit its needs. The video plays when the plugin is loaded, see demo.

```
$('video')[0].play();
```

[**CODEPEN**](http://$('video')[0].play();)

#### Demo

```js
// variables
var $header_top = $('.header-top');
var $nav = $('nav');



// toggle menu 
$header_top.find('a').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('open-menu');
});



// fullpage customization
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  sectionsColor: ['#B8AE9C', '#348899', '#F2AE72', '#5C832F', '#B8B89F'],
  sectionSelector: '.vertical-scrolling',
  slideSelector: '.horizontal-scrolling',
  navigation: true,
  slidesNavigation: true,
  controlArrows: false,
  anchors: ['firstSection', 'secondSection', 'thirdSection', 'fourthSection', 'fifthSection'],
  menu: '#menu',

  afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
    $header_top.css('background', 'rgba(0, 47, 77, .3)');
    $nav.css('background', 'rgba(0, 47, 77, .25)');
    if (index == 5) {
      $('#fp-nav').hide();
    }
    $('video')[0].play();// <=======================[ADD THIS]
  },

  onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
    if (index == 5) {
      $('#fp-nav').show();
    }
  },

  afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {
    if (anchorLink == 'fifthSection' && slideIndex == 1) {
      $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false, 'up');
      $header_top.css('background', 'transparent');
      $nav.css('background', 'transparent');
      $(this).css('background', '#374140');
      $(this).find('h2').css('color', 'white');
      $(this).find('h3').css('color', 'white');
      $(this).find('p').css({
        'color': '#DC3522',
        'opacity': 1,
        'transform': 'translateY(0)'
      });
    }
  },

  onSlideLeave: function(anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction) {
    if (anchorLink == 'fifthSection' && slideIndex == 1) {
      $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true, 'up');
      $header_top.css('background', 'rgba(0, 47, 77, .3)');
      $nav.css('background', 'rgba(0, 47, 77, .25)');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans:300,400,700);

/* ICON STYLES - ICON FROM: http://fontastic.me/
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

@font-face {
  font-family: "untitled-font-1";
  src: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/untitled-font-1.eot");
  src: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/untitled-font-1.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/untitled-font-1.woff") format("woff"), url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/untitled-font-1.ttf") format("truetype"), url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/untitled-font-1.svg#untitled-font-1") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[class^="icon-"]:after,
[class*=" icon-"]:after {
  font-family: "untitled-font-1";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  speak: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-up-open-big {
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon-up-open-big:after {
  content: "a";
  font-size: 2.5em;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  color: black;
  -webkit-transition: color .3s;
  transition: color .3s;
}

.icon-up-open-big:hover:after {
  color: white;
}

.scroll-icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}


/* HELPER CLASSES
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.l-left {
  float: left;
}

.l-right {
  float: right;
}

.end {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(300px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(300px);
  transform: translateY(300px);
  -webkit-transition: opacity, -webkit-transform 1s;
  transition: opacity, transform 1s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}


/* RESET-GENERAL STYLES
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: .18em;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}


/* NAV STYLES
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

.header-top {
  background: rgba(0, 47, 77, .3);
  height: 70px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 12;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  line-height: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}

h1 a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.toggle-menu {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}

.toggle-menu i {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  width: 30px;
  left: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.toggle-menu i:nth-child(1) {
  top: 16px;
}

.toggle-menu i:nth-child(2) {
  top: 24px;
}

.toggle-menu i:nth-child(3) {
  top: 32px;
}

.open-menu i:nth-child(1) {
  top: 25px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}

.open-menu i:nth-child(2) {
  background: transparent;
}

.open-menu i:nth-child(3) {
  top: 25px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
}

nav {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(0, 47, 77, .25);
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s;
  transition: all 3s;
}

.open-menu~nav {
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 80px 0;
  z-index: 15;
  height: calc(90vh - 70px);
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

nav li {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

nav li a {
  font-size: 2em;
  display: block;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: background .3s;
  transition: background .3s;
}

nav li:nth-child(odd) a,
body.fp-viewing-fifthSection-1 #menu li:nth-child(5) a {
  background: #962D3E;
}

nav li:nth-child(even) a {
  background: #aa3346;
}

nav li:nth-child(odd) a:hover {
  background: #9e2f41;
}

nav li:nth-child(even) a:hover {
  background: #c53c52;
}

nav li.active a,
body.fp-viewing-fifthSection-1 #menu li:last-child a {
  background: #453659;
}


/* SECTION STYLES - fullPage.js 
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

section {
  text-align: center;
  /*background: url('https://unsplash.it/1910/1221?image=626') no-repeat center / cover;*/
}

h2 {
  text-transform: lowercase;
  font-size: 4em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2.8em;
}


/* SLIDENAV STYLES - fullPage.js 
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

#fp-nav ul li a span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li a span {
  background: white;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  margin: -4px 0 0 -4px;
}

#fp-nav ul li a.active span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li a.active span,
#fp-nav ul li:hover a.active span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li:hover a.active span {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: -8px 0 0 -8px;
  background: transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #24221F;
}


/* MQ STYLES
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  nav ul {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  nav li {
    margin-top: 1px;
  }
  nav li a {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  .scroll-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  html {
    font-size: 50%;
  }
  .open-menu~nav {
    padding: 20px 0;
  }
  nav li a {
    padding: 3px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.6.6/jquery.fullPage.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<header>
  <div class="header-top clearfix">
    <h1 class="l-left"><a href="#firstSection">Your Logo</a></h1>
    <a class="l-right toggle-menu" href="#">
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
    </a>
  </div>

  <nav class="hide">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li data-menuanchor="firstSection">
        <a href="#firstSection" title="First Section">First Section</a>
      </li>
      <li data-menuanchor="secondSection">
        <a href="#secondSection" title="Second Section">Second Section</a>
      </li>
      <li data-menuanchor="thirdSection">
        <a href="#thirdSection" title="Second Section">Third Section</a>
      </li>
      <li data-menuanchor="fourthSection">
        <a href="#fourthSection" title="Fourth Section">Fourth Section</a>
      </li>
      <li data-menuanchor="fifthSection">
        <a href="#fifthSection" title="First Slide">First Slide</a>
      </li>
      <li data-menuanchor="fifthSection/1">
        <a href="#fifthSection/1" title="Second Slide">Second Slide</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<div id="fullpage">
  <section class="vertical-scrolling">
    <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth" style="height: 100%; object-fit: cover;">
                    <source  src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                   </video>
  </section>
  <section class="vertical-scrolling">
    <h2>fullPage.js</h2>
    <h3>This is the second section</h3>
  </section>
  <section class="vertical-scrolling">
    <h2>fullPage.js</h2>
    <h3>This is the third section</h3>
  </section>
  <section class="vertical-scrolling">
    <h2>fullPage.js</h2>
    <h3>This is the fourth section</h3>
  </section>
  <section class="vertical-scrolling">
    <div class="horizontal-scrolling">
      <h2>fullPage.js</h2>
      <h3>This is the fifth section and it contains the first slide (actually section == first slide)</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="horizontal-scrolling">
      <h2>fullPage.js</h2>
      <h3>This is the second slide</h3>
      <p class="end">Thank you!</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.6.6/jquery.fullPage.min.js'></script>
```